# SQL Join with >= or between logic

Tags: sql, join, amazon-redshift, operator-keyword

I have two tables that look like this.

Table 1:

```
video_ref_raw_media_id | start_seconds | end_seconds | step
ABC001                 | 0:00          | 0:30        | 1
ABC001                 | 0:31          | 1:30        | 2
ABC001                 | 1:31          | 2:30        | 3
ABC002                 | 0:00          | 0:35        | 1
ABC002                 | 0:36          | 1:46        | 2
ABC002                 | 1:47          | 2:44        | 3
```

Table 2:

```
video_ref_raw_media_id | start_seconds | end_seconds | label
ABC001                 | 0:10          | 0:11        | green
ABC001                 | 0:15          | 0:16        | black
ABC001                 | 1:45          | 1:46        | green
ABC002                 | 0:20          | 0:21        | red
```

I want to join table 1 to table 2 based upon 1 the video_ref_raw_media_id and 2 based upon the step in table 1. The only way to do this is if the label that was applied in table 2 occurred with in the time frame of the step in table 1 (between start_seconds and end_seconds). I hope this makes some sense.

I think the sql would look something like

```
Select * from 
"Table 1"
LEFT JOIN "Table 2" on "Table 1".video_ref_raw_media_id="Table 2".video_ref_raw_media_id and (Table2.start_seconds>=Table1.start_seconds and Table2.end_seconds<=Table1.end_seconds)
```

However, this does not work. Any ideas?

Ideal output:

```
video_ref_raw_media_id | start_seconds | end_seconds | step | label
ABC001                 | 0:00          | 0:30        | 1    | green
ABC001                 | 0:00          | 0:30        | 1    | black
ABC001                 | 0:31          | 1:30        | 2    | null
ABC001                 | 1:31          | 2:30        | 3    | green
ABC002                 | 0:00          | 0:35        | 1    | red
ABC002                 | 0:36          | 1:46        | 2    | null
ABC002                 | 1:47          | 2:44        | 3    | null
```

Comment: 1. What dbms are you using? 2. What do *you* mean by "does not work"?

Comment: 3. What is the data type of those columns storing the time?

Comment: does not work = query execution failed. invalid reference to from-clause for entry "Table 1"

Comment: Video_ref_raw_media_id = VARCHAR, start_seconds = float, end_seconds = float, step = VARCHAR, label = VARCHAR. This data is in redshift.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please in code questions give a [mre].  When you get a result that you don't expect/understand, stop trying to find your overall goal & find out what your misunderstanding is.--Isolate the first unexpected/misunderstood subexpression & its input & output & learn what misconception, typo, wrong reasoning, etc led to it. (Debugging fundamental.) Ask about that. Please don't ask us to write your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get rid of the semi-column and it would work, and cast to int:

```
    Select * from 
    "Table 1"
    LEFT JOIN "Table 2" on "Table 1".video_ref_raw_media_id="Table 2".video_ref_raw_media_id 
    and cast((replace(Table2.start_seconds,':','') as int)>=cast(replace(Table1.start_seconds,':','') as int) 
and cast(replace(Table2.end_seconds,':','') as int)<=cast(replace(Table1.end_seconds,':','') as int))
```